# datetime and timezone: utc conversion. Am I doing it right?

Tags: python, django, datetime, datetime-format

I'm in France. `UTC+02:00`
If I try on my PC :

```
print(timezone.now())
print(make_aware(datetime.now()))
```

I get this:

```
2017-05-24 20:46:02.426011+00:00
2017-05-24 22:46:02.426011+02:00
```

In which format should I write the datetime?
Here's my mixin I wrote for all my forms and I'm not sure if I did the right thing. The idea behind this is: I 'convert' all datetimes I get to 
`UTC+00:00` (== `UTC`) and I write them, and when I have to display them, I call `make_aware()` so it takes the language of the client browser and use the `UTC+xx:xx` of the browser.

```
# from django.utils.datetime_safe import datetime as datetime_safe

class DateUtilsMixin(object):

    @staticmethod
    def make_date_aware(d):
        # make d "aware"
        if type(d) is str:
            return make_aware(
                datetime_safe.combine(parse_date(d),
                                      time(0, 0, 0)),
                timezone=pytz.timezone('UTC'))
        elif type(d) is datetime_date:
            return make_aware(
                datetime_safe.combine(d, time(0, 0, 0)),
                timezone=pytz.timezone('UTC'))
        return d
```

Django itself activates the timezone of the client's browser (which is great) so I'm asking if my code seems "logical" and do/should adapt itself to various client's timezones. For example the Django app would work the same way if I'm in China and if I'm at Tahiti and if I'm in Australia (with the server in France)

Am I doing the right stuff, and if not, what should I change to be sure to display the date time to the right timezone, using the client's language?

Comment: That's not possible only using the client's language, you need to know client's timezone as well. In that case, you'll save the datetime object as datetime-naive object, and you'll apply datetime localization using `from django.utils.timezone import activate` like this `activate(user_timezone_str)`.

Comment: @KostasLivieratos I may not be clear enough, so i've edited my question, I'm very sorry for that, I hope it's better now.

Comment: It's not the case that "Django itself activates the timezone of the client's browser". See [Selecting the current time zone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone): "The current time zone is the equivalent of the current locale for translations. However, there’s no equivalent of the `Accept-Language` HTTP header that Django could use to determine the user’s time zone automatically. Instead, Django provides time zone selection functions. Use them to build the time zone selection logic that makes sense for you."

Comment: So if I understand what you say, I should use the current locale (nevermind how I've set it up (including `settings.py`)) and use `make_aware()` before sending my answer to the client? If so, may I ask you to answer so I can check your answer as valid, and I'll think about how to handle this "properly". Thank you very much